Question about converting raw binary glTF (JSON) to .glb or .glTF
I have a question about converting the above-mentioned file.
The glTF JSON looks as follows:

Is there a working method or a package that can do it in flutter?
So far I couldn't find anything that works. :-/
Trying some methods that I found on the internet, but they are not converting to my expected result.
As well-tried two packages from pub.dev they are as well not working.
I don't need a full solution, at least the right direction, since  i never used glTF or glb before.

Welcome to StackOverflow :) As your question stands right now, it is very hard to answer. Please edit your question and include how the glTF JSON looks exactly (aas text, not as an image) and exactly which methods you have tried already and where you failed. Cheers :)
